# All unix Timestamp convert to day-month-year

Tags: mysql

I've got a Weatherstation and Raspberry Pi which saves all data to a SQL database name weewx in archive. All the data is in Unix timestamp. I would like to use a query which collect all data and convert the unix timestamp into normal data.

Weewx

```
select * FROM archive where unix_timestamp()
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this way as @Abhik Chakraborty suggest.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219) as DateTime, other_columns FROM archive ;
```

See More:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime